# Wordpress Ajax for logged in user fails

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, https

I am using wordpress 4.1.1. wp-admin and other several pages (like login, register...) use https connection.
My goal is create ajax request for adding tickets to system.

So I can not call function for logged in user it calls function for not-logged in user. But when I add https for this page it`s work fine for me.

**Question:**

How I can keep user logged in on https and http, so `is_user_logged_in()` in amin-ajax.php works fine?

Answer (score 3):

Just need to add one more line with your code :

```
for logged in users : 

add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_request', 'my_request' ); //calling function "my_request" for logged in users only

for non-logged in users : 

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_request', 'my_request' ); //calling function "my_request" for non-logged in users
```

for more information about addition of ajax in wordpress, just check here : http://www.wptricks24.com/how-to-use-ajax-wordpress/

Comment: I have used this functions, as I explained all works fine on https pages, but on http it`s doesn`t work, when I debug this problem, I have found that is_user_logged_in() in admin-ajax.php doesn`t works fine for logged in user... so my question was how to keep user logged in for ajax request

Answer (score -1):

I found solution, but it1s not pretty good, we should use `http://example.com/wp-admin/admn-ajax.php` url not `https://example.com/wp-admin/admn-ajax.php`, that I have used.